# Messaging content script works when using 'webRequest.onBeforeRequest()' as the trigger but not when using 'webRequest.onCompleted()'

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, web-extension

I finished writting my first extension and it works as I programmed it, but after completing it, I realised I made a mistake in its design, currently its designed to alert me before a event occurs (`webRequest.onBeforeRequest()`), I want to be alerted after the event has occurred and completed (`webRequest.onCompleted()`).

I tried changing, `webRequest.onBeforeRequest()` to `webRequest.onCompleted()` and make the necessary adjustments elsewhere but it just keeps throwing errors. I have removed as much irrelevant code as I can to keep my example short. I would appreciate any help.

**manifest file:**

```
{
    "name": "shell",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",

    "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["content.js"]
        }
      ],
    "permissions": ["tabs","activeTab", "webRequest", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

**Content.js file:**

```
"use strict";

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request) => {
  console.log("Message from the background script:");
  console.log(request.greeting);
  return Promise.resolve({ response: "Hi from content script" });
});
```

**background.js file:**

```
activeTab = browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true,active: true,})  //tabs.sendMessage must always send a message to a specific tab. Use this to get a tab
function onError(error){console.log("error")}
function sendMessageToTabs(activeTab) {
      browser.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.tabId, { greeting: "Hi from background script" })
         .then((response) => {
            console.log("Message from the content script:");
            console.log(response.response); 
         })
         .catch(onError);
    }
// Trigger the messaging event when wiki/vihicle is visited
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(sendMessageToTabs, {urls:["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle"]});
```

The above works perfectly fine, the content script responds back to the background script, on the console when I visit wiki/vehicle:

```
Message from the content script:
Hi from content script
```

#### Where I am going wrong

But when I try to **only** rework the **background.js** file, so that it uses `webRequest.onCompleted()` rather than `webRequest.onBeforeRequest`, my extension stops working. I get the error:

```
Error: Type error for parameter tabId (Integer -1 is too small (must be at least 0)) for tabs.sendMessage.
```

The reworked **background.js file** is:

```
activeTab = browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true,active: true,})  //tabs.sendMessage must always send a message to a specific tab. Use this to get a tab
function onError(error){console.log("error")}
function sendMessageToTabs(activeTab) {
      browser.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.tabId, { greeting: "Hi from background script" })
         .then((response) => {
            console.log("Message from the content script:");
            console.log(response.response);     //response is the object passed back by the content script
         })
         .catch(onError);
    }
browser.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(sendMessageToTabs, {urls:["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle"]});   // this is used to trigger the messaging event
```

---

**Edit1**:

as per  @wOxxOm suggestion, after reading the documentation again, I added the property `types['main_frame']` the `background.js` file looks like:

```
activeTab = browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true,active: true,})  //tabs.sendMessage must always send a message to a specific tab. Use this to get a tab
function onError(error){console.log("error")}
function sendMessageToTabs(activeTab) {
      browser.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.tabId, { greeting: "Hi from background script" })
         .then((response) => {
            console.log("Message from the content script:");
            console.log(response.response);     //response is the object passed back by the content script
         })
         .catch(onError);
    }
browser.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(sendMessageToTabs, {urls:["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle"], types['main_frame']});   // this is used to trigger the messaging event
```

but I am still getting this error:`Error: Type error for parameter tabId (Integer -1 is too small (must be at least 0)) for tabs.sendMessage.`

Comment: Your code intercepts all requests, not just the main one. You need to specify `types:['main_frame']`, see the documentation.

Comment: Actually, webRequest may be the wrong API, depending on what you want to achieve `webNavigation.onCompleted` may be the right choice.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I tried your suggestion but I continue to get the same error. I made an edit to my question, reporting back on your suggestions. Please take a look. I dont understand why `webRequest.onBeforeRequest()` correctly passes the tab id but `webRequest.onCompleted()` passes `-1` as a tab id, which the docs state is a result of the request not being associated with a tab.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I actually need `webRequest.onCompleted()`. The website I am targeting is one of these modern "app" sites, so the tite bar and url never changes. I am trying to target a event that automatically occurs by rellying on when the website request a resource on the background. I have tested for this event on the site manually and works as I expect it.

Comment: In that case you don't need the background script at all - you can detect the changes directly in the content script, [example](/a/39508954).

Comment: @wOxxOm, I whish that it were so but I need a background script as the core of my script consists of starting a Powershell/Python script via "Native Messaging" every time the resource `https://some/site.com` is requested and the page has fully loaded. My extension consists of three steps, when a certain resource is requested and loaded, ask the content script to get a something from the DOM, finally the background script should pass that same value to a Python programme via "Native messaging". I have figured out everything but `webRequest.onCompleted()`

Comment: Apparently the site makes the request in its service worker, which is why its tabId is -1. You can just get the list of all tabs matching the URL of the site e.g. `chrome.tabs.query({url: '*://site.com/*'})` and send a message to all found tabs. Note that if the resource is not the main page itself then it's not `main_frame` but something else e.g. `xmlhttprequest` depending on how that request is made.

Comment: @ I see, that makes sense, I will try your suggestion and see what I end up with. Thank you for helping, I really apprciate it. If I ever figure it out I will report back with an answer.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I finally got your hints and figured it out. updated with an answer cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

So after re reading all of [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) comments, especially his last one. I started to try random URLs such as the BBC and McDonalds etc. And they all worked. I did not even need to specify `type: ["main_frame"]`. I also tried it on my final site and it worked too.
It seems, my failing came down to using Wikipedia as an example to test my code on, something I initially picked sole SO's "reproduceable" example convention. Lesson learned.

The final **Background.js** is:

```
function onError(error){console.log("error")}
function sendMessageToTabs(activeTab) {
      browser.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.tabId, { greeting: "Hi from background script" })
         .then((response) => {
            console.log("Message from the content script:");
            console.log(response.response);     //response is the object passed back by the content script
         })
         .catch(onError);
    }
browser.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(sendMessageToTabs, {urls:["https://final/web/site/here.com"]});  //This time it does not send `-1`
```

I just want to thank w0xx0m, I doubt I would have caught without their patient back and forth with me, cheers